# Connect to raspi over ethernet with no known IP

Tags: headless, dhcp

Is it possible to set the IP of a raspi from another connected device?

I have my raspi plugged into the ethernet port on my iMac. The raspi doesn't have an IP (as far as I can tell), so I can't ssh into it.

I tried following http://blog.angryturtle.com/2013/02/setting-up-raspberry-pi-for-osx.html, but ping'ing the broadcast address didn't return any other IPs. My mac, however, gives itself an IP.
*[Interestingly, when I pinged the broadcast IP, the pi's ethernet lights flashed. So maybe it* did *have an IP? Is there another way to find it out?]*

Is there some way I can force a static IP to the raspi, from my mac? There's nothing else on the "network" — it's just the mac and the raspi connected by a single ethernet cable.

I do have a monitor, so I could easily fix this, but I was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. Must not have been working before.

Once Internet Sharing (I have mine sharing Wifi --> Ethernet) is turned on, type

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

then plug in the raspberry pi, or whatever device you have. You should see the IP show up. For me, it was `192.168.2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled `ipv6` on my Pi running Raspbian and can connect from OS X using `ssh`.
Append `ipv6` to `/etc/modprobe` to enable ipv6.

I can connect from OS X using either ssh pi@fe80::ba27:ebff:fe19:5b37%en0 or more easily as ssh pi@NamePi.local

This is OK as far as it goes, but still has some limitations, as not everything seems to support ipv6. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14705/8697

AFAIK Internet Sharing will allocate an IP to the Pi, but won't let you use to connect to the Pi from the Mac.

Comment: no, it worked. I am able to do `ssh pi@192.168.2.3` or vnc. Internet sharing also allows me to tunnel through my mac to get an actual internet connection.